# Setting unsigned byte to ArrayBuffer

Tags: javascript, dataview, arraybuffer

I know that you can do

```
const buffer = new ArrayBuffer(16);
const dataView = new DataView(buffer);
dataView.setUint8(1, 4)
console.log(dataView.getUint8(1)); // 1
```

However, I would like to set an unsigned byte before the `dataView` deceleration line, so would it be possible to do this without having access to `dataView` hence would if be possible to set an unsigned byte of `4` at the byte offset `1` to the ArrayBuffer instead of using `dataView.setUint8(1, 4)`?

Or alternatively would it be to convert a DataView to an ArrayBuffer?

Comment: What's your issue with `dataView.setUint8(1, 4)`?

Comment: @Thomas I don't necessarily have any issues with it, I just need an ArrayBuffer instead of a DataView so I realised there may be an alternative solution to this so I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the important thing you're missing is that a `DataView` is just a View. So when you do `dataView.setUint8(1, 4)` you *do* modify the `buffer`. The `dataView` itself does not hold the data, just a reference to the buffer. So your code already does what you want. To get an ArrayBuffer of it just use the original buffer:

```
const buffer = new ArrayBuffer(16);
const dataView = new DataView(buffer);
dataView.setUint8(1, 4)
console.log(dataView.getUint8(1)); // 4
console.log(new Uint8Array(buffer)) // [ 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
```